# Understanding RS256 and SHA256 during JWT Token creation

Tags: php, jwt, rsa, sha, rs256

I am creating a JWT Token using a private key in PHP. For this I am using the OpenSSL library.
Before anything I will share my code :

**PHP**

```
    $header = [
        self::ALG => self::RS256,
        self::TYP => self::JWT
    ];
    $payload = [
        "iss" => $this->getClientID(),
        "iat" => time(),
        "exp" => time()+999
    ];
    $header = base64_encode(json_encode($header));
    $payload = base64_encode(json_encode($payload));
    $token = $header.".".$payload;
    $pkey = openssl_pkey_get_private($this->getPrivateKey(), $this->getPassPhrase());
    openssl_sign($token, $signature, $pkey, 'sha256'); //no algorithm specifically for rs256
    $sign = base64_encode($signature);
    return $token.".".$sign;
```

So, this JWT Token will be used for authentication in a server which I am trying to hit. But I get the response from the external server as a `Bad Request`, problem happening in my JWT token creation.

With same credentials, I tried in javascript using the library `jsrsasign` and it then gives me the correct response.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
// Header
var oHeader = { alg: 'RS256', typ: 'JWT' };
// Payload
var oPayload = {};
var tNow = rs.KJUR.jws.IntDate.get('now');
var tEnd = tNow + 1000;
oPayload.iss = "playground.pizza";
oPayload.iat = tNow;
oPayload.exp = tEnd;
var sHeader = JSON.stringify(oHeader);
var sPayload = JSON.stringify(oPayload);
var pkey = "my private key" //I replaced all the new line with \n here and had in one line
var prvKey = rs.KEYUTIL.getKey(pkey, "my_pass_phrase");
var sJWT = rs.KJUR.jws.JWS.sign("RS256", sHeader, sPayload, prvKey);
ultraSecureToken = sJWT;
```

One difference which I can clearly see is that for the `signature generation function` in the php end I am passing `sha256` as the algorithm and in the JavaScript `RS256` is passed.

I read about how sha256 is just a hashing algorithm and RS256 is used for encoding, but in all the libraries I found in php, they were internally passing `sha256` only in the `openssl_sign` function. And `openssl_sign` doesn't have RS256 as an algorithm parameter.

So, firstly is there anywhere where I went wrong.

Secondly, is there a way we can generate a signature using RS256 in php.

PS : I am looking for solution in php.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The return-value of [`KJUR.jws.JWS.sign`](https://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/api/symbols/KJUR.jws.JWS.html#.sign) consists of three portions separated by a dot. The first part is the Base64url-encoded JSON-string `sHeader`, the second part is the Base64url-encoded JSON-string `sPayload` and the third part is the Base64url-encoded signature. The data to be signed consist of the first two portions including the dot separating the two portions. [RS256](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518#section-3.1) means that SHA256 and RSA with RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 padding is used for the signature. This can also be easily verified online, e.g. [here](https://8gwifi.org/rsasignverifyfunctions.jsp), whereby `SHA256withRSA` is to be selected as the algorithm.
- [`openssl_sign`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-sign.php) also uses RSA with RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 padding and therefore creates the *same* signature with SHA256, assuming the same key and the same data to be signed are applied.
- `jsrsasign` uses [Base64 *url*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table)-encoding ([RFC4648, sect. 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-5)), while PHP (or more precisely the `base64_encode`-method) uses *standard* Base64-encoding ([RFC4648, sect. 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-4)), which most likely is one cause of the issue. This means that the encoding in the current PHP-code must be changed to Base64url, e.g. [here](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.base64-encode.php#121767).
- Of course, the underlying JSON-strings in the PHP-code (`$header`, `$payload` and `$token`) must also be identical to their counterparts in the JavaScript-code, otherwise the signature will differ. Since the PHP-code is incomplete, this cannot be checked and could be another cause of the problem.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer more than 10 times.
Btw, how is the php code incomplete?

Comment: _Incomplete_ only in the sense that some definitions are lacking in the posted snippet, e.g. `ALG`, `TYP`, `getClientID()`,... Therefore, _substitute_ definitions for `$header` and `$payload` had to be used, so that the _original_ definitions remained untested. Nothing serious.